# Responsivness:div resizes depending on inline div

Tags: html, css, grid

First div element is facing downwards,i've had this kind of problem and could not understand it, i'm just making simple grid layout 24% | 50% | 24% but as you see first div is doing weird thing, if you solve it  and explain why this phenomenon happens and am i doing this simple grid correctly please give your opinions,thanks in adnvance.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 25px;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.nav-top {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f00000;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.row p {
  font-size: 90%;
  float: left;
}

.nav-top-col-sm {
  width: 24%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-top-col-sm span {
  float: right;
}

.nav-top-col-lg {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-top">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="nav-top-col-sm">
      <span>En</span>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-top-col-lg">
      <p>FB,Twitter,Google,Wifi,Youtube</p>
      <p>market</p>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-top-col-sm">
      <p>My Account</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Col-->
  </div>
  <!-- Row -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the display property to **inline or inline block**, you should set

`vertical-align: middle;` for them.

Also u dont need to set the width to 24% to get them on one line.
U need to set the `font size:0` on the parent, and give individual font sizes to each inline-block.

This happens because, the inline blocks have some white-space, which pushes them on next line, when 25% width is given.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 25px;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.nav-top {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f00000;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.row p {
  font-size: 90%;
  float: left;
}

.nav-top-col-sm {
  width: 24%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.nav-top-col-sm span {
  float: right;
}

.nav-top-col-lg {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-top">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="nav-top-col-sm">
      <span>En</span>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-top-col-lg">
      <p>FB,Twitter,Google,Wifi,Youtube</p>
      <p>market</p>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-top-col-sm">
      <p>My Account</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Col-->
  </div>
  <!-- Row -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Just what i wanted to know and wanted to do,very nice man thanks a lot!